# Error: Call to a member function execute() on string

Tags: magento2

I am trying to send the form's data to admin panel from phtml. However, it returned an error for the HTML form's class, how can I run the php function for passing data to html and send it to admin?

Myvendor/Mymodule/Controller/Index/Send.php

```
<?php
 namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Controller\Index;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
 use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
 use Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail;

 class Send extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{

/**
 * Recipient email config path
 */
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'email_section/sendmail/email_section_sendmail_email_template';
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
 */
protected $_transportBuilder;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
 */
protected $inlineTranslation;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 */
protected $scopeConfig;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
 */
protected $_escaper;
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_escaper = $escaper;
}

/**
 * Post user question
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function execute()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    if (!$post) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

    $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

    try {
        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($post);

        $error = false;

        $sender = [
            'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['name']),
            'email' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['email']),
        ];

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('email_section_sendmail_email_template') // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // this is using frontend area to get the template file
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
            ->getTransport();


        $transport->sendMessage(); ;
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
            __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
        );

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        $this->messageManager->addError(
            __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.'.$e->getMessage())
        );

    }

    return $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
}

}
```

Myvendor/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/popup.phtml

```
<?php

/**
* @var \Myvendor\Mymodule\Controller\Index\Send $myBlock2
*/

$block3 = $myBlock2->excute();

?>

<div class="content" style="display:none" id="popup_content">
<form
    class="form enquire"
    id="enquire-form"
    action="<?php $block3 ?>"
    method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label> <br>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text"><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label> <br>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email"><br>
    <label for="message">Message:</label> <br>
    <input id="message" name="message" type="text"><br>
    <label for="product_name">Product Name:</label> <br>
    <input id="product_name" name="product_name" type="text"><br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Myvendor/Mymodule/view/frontend/email/email_file.html

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

   <table class="message-details">
    <tr>
           <td><b>{{trans "Name"}}</b></td>
    <td>{{var data.name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>{{trans "Email"}}</b></td>
    <td>{{var data.email}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>{{trans "Product Name"}}</b></td>
    <td>{{var data.product_name}}</td>
</tr>
  </table>
  <p><b>{{trans "Comments"}}</b></p>
  <p>{{var data.message}}</p>

  {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In `phtml` file, only `$block` is predefined variable.
   `$bock1`, `$block2`,... are not predefined variables, so you can't use these variables.
2. 

- You don't need to (and can not) call `$block->execute()` to execute the controller method. When the form is submitted (click the submit button) from the frontend, the corresponding controller will be called automatically by Magento.
- In your phtml file, change your `action` from `action="<?php $block3 ?>"` to `action="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>"`

And declare `getFormAction()` method in your block: Assume your Block file path is `app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/Block/MyBlock.php`, open the block file to declare `getFormAction()` method:

```
public function getFormAction()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('frontName/controllerName/actionName', ['_secure' => true]);
    }
```

Where:

- `frontName` specifies the frontName of the FrontController to use. It is declared in `routes.xml`. In your case, your controller work in frontend, the routers.xml file is located in `app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/etc/frontend/routes.xml`
- `controllerName` specifies the name of the controller
- `actionName` specifies the [action class](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/routing/#action-class) to execute on the controller class

Assume your `frontName` is **productenquiry**, your `controllerName` is **Index**, your `actionName` is **Send**, your route path should be: `productenquiry/index/send` and your `getFormAction()` method should be:

```
public function getFormAction()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('productenquiry/index/send', ['_secure' => true]);
    }
```

Your module is related to Magento_Contact core module, so you can take a look at that module to build your module: **vendor/magento/module-contact**

Comment: Hi Tu, thanks for your answer, sorry that I am new at Magento2 and PHP. It's fine after changed to "action="<?= $block->escapUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>"". But it has no response after clicking submit button. May I know did I miss some settings?

Comment: Yeah, I know you are new so I've written the details instructions for you. Let's open the Browser Developer Tool (you can do it by Right click inside the page then choosing **Inspect**), change to the Console tab to see if there are any errors then post it here or take a screenshot and post it here, I'll debug.

Comment: I tested as per your advice, and no error showed in the console, as this form is a pop-up modal, it just closed after clicking submit. Does it mean the controller did not run execute function?

Comment: I'll check and let you know.

Comment: Even if your form is in a popup, it still calls the controller if the form is submitted. I've tested your code, and it works. Let's right-click on the **Name** field and select **Inspect** to check whether the form action is correct or not.Take a look at my screenshot https://i.imgur.com/Uta4FVB.png

Comment: I just checked and see the action is empty, below is my code, is it something wrong?

Comment: <?php/**
 * @var \Myvendor\Mymodule\ProductEnquiry\Block\Send $block
 */


?>

<div class="content" style="display:none" id="popup_content">
    <form
        class="form enquire"
        id="enquire-form"
        action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>"
        method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <Label for="#name">Name</Label>
            <input name="name" id="name" title="Name" class="form-control input-text" type="text"/>
        </div>
     ....

Comment: Did you declare (add) the `getFormAction()` method into app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/ProductEnquiry/Block/Send.php as I said in my answer?

Comment: Remember clear the cache after that.

Comment: Yes I have created app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/Block/Send.php

Comment: <?php

namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Send extends Template {
    /**
     * "@"param Template\Context $context
     * "@"param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = []) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

Comment: protected function _prepareLayout() {

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Returns action url for Green Enquire
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction() {

        return $this->getUrl('productenquiry/index/send', ['_secure' => true]);
    }
}

Comment: Does your Block is app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/Block/Send.php or app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/Block/Popup.php or something else? You should check it in the .xml layout file where assign Myvendor/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/popup.phtml to your Block. I think your Block is Popup not Send, if so you should add the `getFormAction()` method there.

Comment: Oh yes, I created 2 blocks for Popup and Send in the Block folder, so I should combine them in 1 file?

Comment: Yes, that means you using Popup block, not Send block. You should adding `getFormAction() ` method as I said in the answer to your Popup block and remove Send block. Let me know if it works

Comment: Yes, now it works for calling out the function but I got another error while submitting the form, I will try to find out the root cause. Thanks and have a gd day!